# Zf2 Db Sessions Inserts but doesn't update sessions in database

Tags: php, database, session, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have configured database sessions in my zf2 (skeleton) application to use a typical MySQL database as stated in the documentation. However, the application only inserts sessions, it never updates the specific row. So on every refresh a new session is created and previously stored information cannot be retrieved.

My configuration is as follows:

```
global.php
-------------------


        'session_config'    =>  array
                                (
                                    'cache_expire'          =>  2419200,
                                    'cookie_lifetime'       =>  2419200,
                                    'gc_maxlifetime'        =>  2419200,
                                    'cookie_path'           =>  '/',
                                    'cookie_secure'         =>  TRUE,
                                    'remember_me_seconds'   =>  2419200,
                                    'use_cookies'           =>  true,
                                )
```

My sessions table is created as follows (database user has select, insert & update privs):

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` 
(
  `id` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `modified` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lifetime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My database sessions are configured within a factory closure in Application/Module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return  array
    (
    'factories' => array
        (
        // Sessions
        'session_manager' => function($serviceManager)
        {
            $sessionOptions = new DbTableGatewayOptions();
            $sessionOptions->setDataColumn('data')
                           ->setIdColumn('id')
                           ->setModifiedColumn('modified')
                           ->setLifetimeColumn('lifetime')                                                                                                 
                           ->setNameColumn('name');                                                                                         
            $dbAdapter              =   $serviceManager->get('utils-db');                                                                                        
            $sessionTableGateway    =   new TableGateway('sessions', $dbAdapter);                                                                                        
            $sessionGateway         =   new DbTableGateway
                                            ($sessionTableGateway, $sessionOptions);                                                                                        
            $config                 =   $serviceManager->get('config');                                                                                        
            $sessionConfig          =   new SessionConfig();                                                                                        
            $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session_config']);                                                                                        
            $sessionManager         =   new SessionManager($sessionConfig);                                                                                        
            $sessionManager->setSaveHandler($sessionGateway);

            return $sessionManager;
        },
        ...
        ...
        ),
    );
}
```

Sessions are initiated in the onBootstrap method:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager           =   $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $serviceManager         =   $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $moduleRouteListener    =   new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $sessionManager         =   $serviceManager->get('session_manager');
    $sessionManager->start();
    Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);

    ...

}
```

I can conceptually understand that zf2 can write/insert into sessions but it either can't select the specific row or it can find the specific row it just can't update it. So I dug into Zend\Session\SaveHandler and found this in the DbTableGateway class:

```
/**
 * Write session data
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @param string $data
 * @return bool
 */
public function write($id, $data)
{
    $data = array(
        $this->options->getModifiedColumn() => time(),
        $this->options->getDataColumn()     => (string) $data,
    );

    $rows = $this->tableGateway->select(array(
        $this->options->getIdColumn()   => $id,
        $this->options->getNameColumn() => $this->sessionName,
    ));

    if ($row = $rows->current()) {
        return (bool) $this->tableGateway->update($data, array(
            $this->options->getIdColumn()   => $id,
            $this->options->getNameColumn() => $this->sessionName,
        ));
    }
    $data[$this->options->getLifetimeColumn()] = $this->lifetime;
    $data[$this->options->getIdColumn()]       = $id;
    $data[$this->options->getNameColumn()]     = $this->sessionName;

    return (bool) $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
}
```

Apparently based on a condition it will update if true and let an insert occur below if not:

```
if ($row = $rows->current()) {
        return (bool) $this->tableGateway->update($data, array(
            $this->options->getIdColumn()   => $id,
            $this->options->getNameColumn() => $this->sessionName,
        ));
    }
```

What's weird to me is the line

```
if ($row = $rows->current()) {
```

The variable $row doesn't seem to be set above but $rows does end up with a proper select statement:

```
SELECT `sessions`.* FROM `sessions` WHERE `id` = :where1 AND `name` = :where2
id is set correctly
name is set correctly
```

I just can't figure out why I can't update my seesions. BTW, I can read data from the sessions in the app just fine. But once the page refreshes all data is gone.

Comment: Are you running the app over HTTPS?

Comment: The line: `if ($row = $rows->current()) {` is basically short hand for: `$row = $rows->current(); if ($row) {`. I.e. setting the `$row` variable and checking for value `null`/`false` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for that kasper. I figured that out after another look. But $row->current shouldn't be returning null when the records are there, hence the problem

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking it's a cookie issue - caused by `cookie_secure` being enabled. Have you tried manually looking up the session ID sent in the cookie?

Comment: Good idea. Yeah, I checked the cookie. It changes on every page refresh. I also played around with my session config to make sure that's where the session options were actually coming from. But, I think you're on to something. I'll look deeper into the configs to see if there is something I can play with. On a side note, it appears to be an issue with the Select. Maybe there's some option messing around with that for the session table gateway. I'll let you know

Comment: Hey Kasper Pedersen. You hit it right on the head. Nice catch, very nice. Seems so straight forward now that I think about it. Do you mind making your comment an actual answer so I can mark it as such!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running the application **exclusively** over HTTPS, you should change the session config option `cookie_secure` to `false` (or omit it - defaults to `false`). When `cookie_secure` is set to `true`, the cookie will only be sent over HTTPS.

On HTTP requests this will cause a new session to be created with each request, as the session cookie is not present in the request.